# Concatenated String Length

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to get all files (incl. path) that have > 100 characters in their combined path+file name, however this is not working:

```
$dir = "C:\Program Files"
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Recurse | 
    ForEach-Object {$_.DirectoryName + "\" + $_.Name} | 
    Measure-Object -Character | 
    Where-Object $_.Length > 100
```

Answer (score 1):

In PowerShell, for relational comparison you need to use `-lt` (less-than) and `-gt` (greater-than) instead of `<` and `>`.

When using `Get-ChildItem` the full path (directory + name) to a file is contained in the `FullName` string property. Inspect the `Length` of the `FullName` string:

```
$dir = Get-ChildItem |Where-Object { $_.FullName.Length -gt 100 }
```

Comment: Actually, I just found that Powershell seems to be limited in the number of characters it can report on.  If we increase the character count to 200, I see that the maximum length of the FileName output is 147 characters (even though I do have FileNames that have 200+ characters).  Any advice?

Comment: @Allen This is due to a limitation in .NET, you might [have to use robocopy to get the full name](http://learn-powershell.net/2013/04/01/list-all-files-regardless-of-260-character-path-restriction-using-powershell-and-robocopy/)